# Where should roles not existing in a JWT be added to an Authentication object?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

We have a Spring Boot server that authenticates users using JWT tokens. Users should be assigned roles based on their identity.

The server that grants tokens does not know what roles users should have in each system, so each system should grant roles based on the identify of the user.

Something like:

1. Authenticate user.
2. (User is authenticated) Look up which roles the user has and add to the Authentication in the security context.
3. Check role. For instance, `@PreAuthorize(hasRole('some_role'))`

My question is:

How should I do this? Or alternatively, should I not do this and handle the situation in another way?

Comment: You are going in the right direction. The user role data is always fetched from db everytime token is checked on each request. The token provides user identification which is used to get user data and then session user object is created which in turn helps in creating security context. And yes your apis will have @PreAuthorize(hasRole('role')) checks as long as each user id will have one single role.

Comment: Now for how to do all of this in code, you will have to study more about spring security

Comment: Ok so it seems worth investigating this track further. Right now I'm thinking of providing a custom version of the JwtAuthenticationProvider. Thanks @BeshambherChaukhwan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was already mentioned, `JwtAuthenticationConverter` is the intended configuration point.

Spring Security will pick it up as a `@Bean`:

```java
@Bean
JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter converter =
        new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(...);
    return converter;
}
```

As was already pointed out in another answer, you can also set one on the DSL.

You can read more in the reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.4/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this by using a custom `jwtAuthenticationConverter`.

```
  http
            ...
            ?.oauth2ResourceServer()
            ?.jwt()
            ?.jwtAuthenticationConverter(customConverter)
```

```
@Component
class CustomConverter(
    private val jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter: JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter
) : Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {

    override fun convert(jwt: Jwt): AbstractAuthenticationToken {
      // Custom logic that adds roles
    }
}
```